# Deployment fails because of obscure REXML setting?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rexml

I'm using EngineYard for my production system. My deployment has Ruby 1.9.3p392. I develop on Ruby 1.9.3p429.

I get notifications from a 3rd party server that contains large XML files (larger than 10K anyway).

After a new deployment, for some reason, all of my notifications from this party are FAILING because the XML is greater than the 10K limit.

So on my dev instance I added the following line to `application.rb`:

```
REXML.entity_expansion_text_limit=102400
```

But that makes my deployment fail. So I look around and try another iteration:

```
REXML::Document.entity_expansion_text_limit=102400
```

Nope, that particular version of Ruby has no idea what I'm talking about.

What can I do to overcome this 10K default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I REXML::Document needs to be `require`d on EngineYard. Here's what I did to fix my deployment.

In `application.rb`:

require 'rexml/document'
   REXML::Document.entity_expansion_text_limit=102400

That appears to have done it.